# how to generate thumbnail from video when upload without using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, thumbnails

To generate thumbnail with trying `ffmpeg` but, can not sure how to `configure ffmpeg on live server`

These instructions are for Linux. I don't know the first thing about `Windows or Mac`.

BUILDING THE FFMPEG-PHP EXTENSION

Build and install PHP if it is not already installed

```
Unpack the ffmpeg-php sources

tar -xjf ffmpeg-php-X.x.x.tbz2
```

Change to the `ffmpeg-php extension` directory and run phpize (included with your PHP installation) to build configuration files.

**NOTE: If your php installation does not include phpize, you may have to install a php-dev package for your distro (usually named: `php-dev, php-devel` or similar)**

cd ffmpeg-php-X.x.x/

```
phpize
Configure and build the extension.

./configure && make
Install the shared extension.

sudo make install
```

If everything went as planned, ffmpeg-php is now installed as a shared extension.

Comment: step:1 download from -> https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
step:2 create folder on c:ffmpeg -> unzip code
step:3 set variable control-panel->system->advance system setting->environment variable-> user variable -> new -> variable name : path , variable value : c:\ffmpeg\bin -> ok
step:4 open command prompt -> type ffmpeg -version

successfully done...

Comment: <html>
<head>
Video Thumbnail
</head>
<body>
 <form action="video-thumbnails.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $ffmpeg = 'c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg';
 $videofile = $_file['file']['tmp_name'];
 $imagefile = "1.jpg";
 $size = "120x90";
 $getfromsecond = "5";
 $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videofile -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $imagefile";
 if(!shell_exec($cmd))
 {
 echo "thumbnail created";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "fail to thumbnail created";
 }
 }
 ?>
</body>
</html>